# Checking database for existing username MEAN Stack

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb, express, mean-stack

I have a somewhat simple question (for you who knows better than me, that is..) about my code for a signup controller.
I am trying to check the database for an existing username when a new user registers on my site. I will provide the code below. Thanks in advance!

```
    app.controller('SignupController', function ($scope, $http, $window) {

        $scope.submitSignup = function () {
            var newUser = {
                username: $scope.username,
                password: $scope.password
            };

            if (newUser.username == db.users.username) {
                alert('Username is already taken.');
            }

            if ($scope.submitsignup.$valid) {
                $http.post('/users', newUser).then(function () {
                    $window.location.href = '/#';
                    alert('Your account has been created!');
                });
            }
            else {
                alert('You messed something up brotha...');
            }
        }});
```

Note: Console in browser says that db is not defined.

Here is how I get users from the database in my server.js file.

```
    app.get('/users', function (req, res, next) {
        db.collection('users', function (err, usersCollection) {
            usersCollection.find().toArray(function (err, users) {
                return res.json(users);
            });
        });
});
```

Comment: where is your db variable coming from?

Comment: That is just me fooling around a bit with the code, I don't really know what I'm doing at this point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I recommend that you look into using the Node module [`passport`](http://passportjs.org/) to handle signups and signins. It's very useful.

On the console side, the problem is straightforward- you don't have access to the `db` variable that you're using in your `server.js`.  It's not defined on the front-end, so it means nothing.

Now, you have *a* solution here with `app.get('/users')` because that code will send a list of all your users from the database to the front-end. I don't think it's a good practice, as is a lot of information to send if you have a lot of users.  **But it will work** if you put your check within your `http.get()` request.

```
$http.get('/users').then(function(result){
    if(result.users.find(newUser.username)){
        alert('Username is taken!');
    } else {
        //continue working
    }
}
```

This should work, but it's *pretty* inefficient.  You should instead change your `app.get` take in a [param](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.params) or [query](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.query) and return a boolean if it's found within your database.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on passport, I will utilize it immediately. Also big thanks for your code sample here, I just followed a guy on youtube step-by-step but the api had so many flaws it's almost unbelievable. Anyway, thanks for your time.